# Probability of an answer occurring a set percentage of the time in a questionnaire using dbinom()

Tags: r

Apologies if this seems extremely simple to most but I'm having trouble getting my head around it as I am very new to this!

I'm looking to calculate a probability of an event occurring a set percentage of the time using dbinom().

Example: A questionnaire is sent to 50 people with one question asking if they use their computers every day. What is the probability that 25/50/75% will respond with "yes"?

dbinom() takes these values: x, size, prob but i'm not sure how to place the percentage into this?

If I want to know what the probability is that 25% will respond with 'yes', would I use 12.5 as x as this is 25% of my size with prob set to 0.5 (yes or no)?

Comment: `qbinom(0.25, 50, 0.5)`.

Comment: 25% of your sample would be 12.5 people, so round up/down to 12 or 13. Then the probability that out of 50 people, with a 0.5 chance of success, there are *exactly* 13 successes, is `dbinom(x = 13, size = 50, prob = 0.5)` = 0.0001078. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Thank you for this, yes it is, I just wanted to be sure. Does this change at all if there is an expected percentage at the start? I.e it has previously been found that 35% of people will respond with yes, what is the probability that exactly 35% will say yes again? Will my probability change at all?